Teenaged Asian boy involved with prostitution
The movie name starts with a "M" and has a "K" in it. 
The only things I can remember is that a young Asian/Chinese/Japanese teen boy travels to a place and meets this girl he likes, but ends up messing around with a girl that two American men want to prostitute but the boy tries to help her. 
They capture her and take her to a club where the boy follows them and ends up fighting with the people in the club. He meets the two American guys but gets beat up. He goes to their hotel (I think) and starts to find them but he ends up following them to a truck port where he finds more girls have been prostituted and fights the two Americans at the same time.
He sees the girl but knows that she isn't a virgin any more because one of the Americans raped her. That's all I can remember. Please help me find this movie.

Was it in English? Color? When do you remember seeing it?

You might be talking about the Indonesian 2009 action movie Merantau (AKA Merantau Warrior) with the same director and leading actor of the later hit The Raid: Redemption. It's about a young Indonesian man who leaves his village and moves to Jakarta, where he comes across a girl and tries to rescue her from a prostitution ring run by two Europeans (who speak in English). He fights their henchmen in a club and later fights both men at the same time at the docks, defeats them and rescues all the girls that they kidnapped and locked in a container. No K in the title, though. The trailer, as well as the entire movie, are available on Youtube.

Oh wow! A pencak silat movie! Never knew such a thing exists. Thanks.
